Angular: pass form input data into text editor and complete the pre-defined sentences
I am receiving data from firebase database and filling out multiple  form inputs with them. I want users to be able to edit those inputs and  as they make changes the I want pre-defined sentences to be updated  based on the changes on text editor. I tried quill and proseMirror texteditors but I  couldn't figure out how to accomplish what I wanted.
I found this example text
For example:
Dear {{firstname}},
This report has been developed by the {{departmentName}}. This  document provides a {{pointInTime}},{{summaryActionableKey}} key lessons  learned in safety framework and concepts.
I want the template keys {{ }} to be filled out automatically with data that we have in the database.
Thanks,
